# How do I move a particular row up in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following dataframe:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(
    [['18-24', 334725], ['25-44', 698261], ['45-64', 273087], ['65+', 15035],['<18', 80841]],
    columns=['age_group', 'total_arrests']
)
```

[image]

How would I move the last row (index=4) to the top of the dataframe? I need to do this because when I plot this in matplotlib, the `<18` group appears at the end, not the beginning:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) with compare column for not equal for indices and pass to [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df_test = df_test.iloc[df_test['age_group'].ne('<18').argsort()]
print (df_test)
  age_group  total_arrests
4       <18          80841
0     18-24         334725
1     25-44         698261
2     45-64         273087
3       65+          15035
```

If value is always last and index values are unique change order with indexing by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df_test = df_test.loc[df_test.index[-1:].tolist() + df_test.index[:-1].tolist()]
print (df_test)
  age_group  total_arrests
4       <18          80841
0     18-24         334725
1     25-44         698261
2     45-64         273087
3       65+          15035
```